# Chi square test in loop for checking pvalue for genotypes

Tags: r, loops, chi-squared

The following is the code I have tried

```
aaxab.res=NULL

chiaaxab <- for (i in 1:length(gt)) {
               observed <- c(aa.count[i], ab.count[i])
               expected <- c(0.5, 0.5)
               chisq.test(observed, p=c(0.5, 0.5))$p.value
               p.value <- ifelse(is.na(T.value ))
               aaxab.res <- c(abxaa.res, p.value)
            }
```

but i keep getting the error :

> ```
> Error in chisq.test(observed, p = c(0.5, 0.5)) :
>   at least one entry of 'x' must be positive.
> ```

Can someone please help to rectify this as I am very new to R

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to compare the expected vs observed in which case your code should be:

```
               ...
               chisq.test(observed, expected, p=c(0.5, 0.5))$p.value
               ...
```

You will receive that error when your observed values are both zeros. eg:

```
observed <- c(0, 0)
chisq.test(observed, p=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

> Error in chisq.test(observed, p = c(0.5, 0.5)) : 
>     at least one entry of 'x' must be positive

If your dataset has zeroes (sometimes normal), and you want the loop to continue without throwing an error you can add a conditional statement to check for zeros:

```
chiaaxab <- for (i in 1:length(gt)) {
  observed <- c(aa.count[i], ab.count[i])
  expected <- c(0.5, 0.5)
  if (aa.count[i] == 0 & ab.count[i] == 0) {
    aaxab.res <- c(abxaa.res, NA)
  } else {
    chisq.test(observed, p=c(0.5, 0.5))$p.value
    p.value <- ifelse(is.na(T.value))
    aaxab.res <- c(abxaa.res, p.value) 
    }
}
```

The above code will add `NA` if two zeroes are detected.

Also not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this line: `p.value <- ifelse(is.na(T.value))`. The syntax is: `ifelse(test, yes, no)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to run this code > aaxab.res=NULL
> chiaaxab <- for (i in 1:length(gt)) {
+   observed <- c(aa.count[i], ab.count[i])
+   expected <- c(0.5, 0.5)
+   if (aa.count[i] == 0 & ab.count[i] == 0) {
+     aaxab.res <- c(abxaa.res, NA)
+   } else {
+     chisq.test(observed, p=c(0.5, 0.5))$p.value
+     p.value <- ifelse(test, yes, no)
+     aaxab.res <- c(abxaa.res, p.value)
+     }
+ } But it generates an error that Error: object 'abxaa.res' not found
Now i am confused about the error

Comment: To be honest your code is a mess. You haven't provided a reproducible example and we have no idea what the different variables contain. `abxaa.res` is an object from your original post. You need to figure out where it's being created and why you are assigning it to `aaxab.res` alongside the p.value.